# Command works in Console, but not in Python Toolbox

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-toolbox

I want to create a memory layer with points in ArcGIS with Python Toolbox. I found an *in_memory* function. Here is the question: Why this command works in Python Console in ArcGIS, but not in Python Toolbox?

```
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management('in_memory','memory_layer', "POINT")
```

Not works, I mean no errors and no effects. Function:

```
x = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management('in_memory','memory_layer', "POINT")
arcpy.AddMessage(str(x))
```

Returns *in_memory\memory_layer*

Any ideas?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import arcpy
import os

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "YY"
        self.alias = ""
        self.tools = [XX]


class XX(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "XX"
        self.description = "YY"
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        parameters = []

        x = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="X",
            name="x",
            datatype="String",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        parameters.append(x)

        y = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Y",
            name="y",
            datatype="String",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        parameters.append(y)

        return parameters

    def isLicensed(self):
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        x = float(parameters[0].valueAsText)
        y = float(parameters[1].valueAsText)
        newpoint = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(x,y), arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
        a = newpoint.firstPoint.X
        b = newpoint.firstPoint.Y
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
        arcpy.env.workspace = "in_memory"
        x = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management('in_memory','memory_layer', "POINT")
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(x))
```

Console log:

> Executing: XX 10 10 Start Time: Fri Apr 22 11:37:26 2016 Running
>   script XX... in_memory\memory_layer Completed script XX... Succeeded
>   at Fri Apr 22 11:37:26 2016 (Elapsed Time: 0,09 seconds)

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @x9663605! Perhaps you need to change your workspace directory? E.g. `import arcpy`, `arcpy.env.workspace = "path/to/directory"`

Comment: Please elaborate on `Not works, I mean no errors and no effects`

Comment: Have you got background geoprocessing enabled? Have you set `canRunInBackground=False` in your toolbox?

Comment: @Joseph : Should I add this line for only memory layer?

Comment: @Luke : Yes, I have it.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov : So, the code is at the bottom. When i run it I have this result: http://pasteboard.co/nknj1By.png
Code: http://pastebin.com/XYsr7kAr

Comment: Please paste the Python code and any errors as text in the question body

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov done

Comment: @x9663605, please tag your question with your ArcGIS version.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed on your system?

Comment: @haff no, only the Arc version